Initialize array inside of function
Is there any way to define a array in the data inside the assignment() function? I'm getting TypeError: Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given..
I'm newbie in Solidity and I know, I can define data outside of function and then assign a new value into it.
contract Function {
    function assignment() public returns (uint) {
        uint[] data = [23, 233, 13];
        return data[0];
    }
}


Try:
function assignment() public returns (uint) {
        uint[3] memory data = [uint(23), uint(233), uint(13)];
        return data[0];
    }

Every reference type has a data location, wich can be memory, storage or calldata. More info in the solidity docs

When you are creating an array inside a function, this array is stored inside the memory.
Memory is another place of storage that is used in Ethereum. It is seen as a stack. You have tried implementing the dynamic array within a function. While it is possible to do that as well, you are most likely to get a revert.
This is because there is a limit to how much the memory can be utilized (There is a limit to the stack and it is based on total gas that is used).
I would suggest using a static array with a known size. Here's the code
function assignment() public pure returns (uint[2] memory){
    uint[2] memory data;
    data[1] = 3;
    return data;
}

Here, a static array of size '2' is created when the function executes. This function is stored in the 'memory' that can be called as the 'run time' memory for a transaction.
Next, the value '3' is stored at the index '1' of the array. When the array is returned, you should get the output [0,3]
Note, that if you instead want to return only a specific value inside the array and not the entire array, then you make the following changes to the code
function assignment() public pure returns (uint memory){
    uint[2] memory data;
    data[1] = 3;
    return data[1];
}

This will return the value '3' when the function is called. In a similar manner, you can declare a uint array of varying size and return data as desired.

Thanks a lot, your description was very clear and complete.
